# Why is my <p> split into three when I insert ul/ol tags in-between it?

Tags: html, css

```
<p>
    <span>Some texts in here?</span>
        <ul>
            <li>And Some here</li>
            <li>Same here</li>
            <li>Here too</li>
        </ul>
</p>
```

The Code above is my HTML code. When I try to style the `<p>` tag, I get three different variants of this `<p>` tag. Before you ask, if there are other `<p>` tags in my HTML document -- there aren't. As an example, when I used `border-radius: 20px; // when I use border-radius property` I get 2 different `<p>` tags with four rounded corners each and I guess 1 is underneath the `<ul>` tag because when I tried to select each tag with `nth-child()` property I can select three children.

Here is my CSS

```
p { 
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px 10px;
        background-color: var(--prompt-back);
        color: var(--foregroundColor);
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;

        &:nth-child(1) {
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0px;
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }
    }
```

```
    ul {
        background-color: var(--prompt-back);
        color: var(--foregroundColor);
        font-size: 13px; 
    }
```

Also, why am I not able to inherit the property of the `<p>` tag in  tags?

What I want to know is what's going on here and get the solution if there is any...

Comment: Look at the valid content for a p tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p The UL tag is not one of them.

Comment: Instead of p tag. Use div tag instead to wrap the elements. p tags can only use sub tags like span, [ <i></i> , <strong></strong>, <b></b>, <u></u> ] and other tags.

Answer (score -1):

`<p>` is a block tag, html doesn't support block tags inside `<p>` tag. If you use any block tag inside `<p>` tag your browser closes `</p>` tag and append your block tags out of `<p>` the tag.

You can use `<div> </div>` for wrap your code.

```
<div>
   <p>
      <span>Some texts in here?</span>
    <ul>
        <li>And Some here</li>
        <li>Same here</li>
        <li>Here too</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example still gets split into multiple `<p>` elements by the browser.